# how to delete selected list items?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an array string that i used in my `Fragment`,and i show the array string items with `setListAdapter` in my list:

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.examlearray);
        final ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str );
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

  final ListView listView = getListView();       
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {...
```

and under my `onActionItemClicked` i want to implement my **deleteSelectedItem()** method,that delete items from my list that selected,and this is my code,but it didn't remove selected item,it is just remove from first of list,and where ever it wants!!!what should I do?,Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
 @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                    //    deleteSelectedItems();

                         Log.i(TAG, "deleteSelectedEntries");
                         SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                        for(int i=0;i<checkedItems.size();++i){

                         if(checkedItems.valueAt(i)){
                            str.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                         }
                        }

                         arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                         mode.finish();
                         return true;
                      }
```

Comment: did you get selected item correctly ? did you check `onActionItemClicked` and `checkedItems` values?

Comment: It seems Your logic is wrong!

Comment: @PareshMayani why and where?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan my checkedItem  contain array of boolean corresponding to each position, if it is true item is checked otherwise it is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code in many situation returned `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`.

**one example:**

you have a list with 14 element, you select first and last index on it. so now in for statement you go trough your list and delete from that:

in this scenario you delete first index of your list, so size of your list became 13, then for remove last item you have tries to access 14th element of your list that is not exists

**How to solve:**

```
for(int i=checkedItems.size()-1 ;i>= 0;i--){

      if(checkedItems.valueAt(i)){
          str.remove(checkedItems.keyAt(i));  
      }
}
```

Comment: I try your code,with this line for(int i=checkedItems.size() ;i> 0;i--) my app at first delete going to crash,and i checked it with changing the array to what you suggested,but it will do the same!it will delete only the last selected item correctly,and instead of others delete whatever it want!i don't know why!do you have another suggestion?

Comment: sorry i have another question,when i rerun my app,all the deleted items back,it seems nothing changed,why?

Comment: what is your mean about " rerun my app "? exit from app and run again? where you save this changes? did you use database

Comment: yes when i exit and run that again.i want to delete the selected item forever,i used a string array and used it as a list,so it's because i have no database?,or there is some way to implement that?

Comment: you must persist selected item in one place like DataBase, so you can't do this without Database.

Answer (score 1):

The key of the `SparseBooleanArray` denotes the position of the selected item in the listview. So instead of `str.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(i));` use `str.remove(checkedItems.keyAt(i));`

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            //    deleteSelectedItems();

            Log.i(TAG, "deleteSelectedEntries");
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i=0;i<checkedItems.size();++i){

            if(checkedItems.valueAt(i)){
                str.remove(checkedItems.keyAt(i));
            }
    }

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mode.finish();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,it's working ,but when I select all the items my app crash!why?

Comment: post the logcat message

Comment: oh it is just working well when i select one item,but when i select more than one item it will crash

Comment: @Ladan see first part of my answer

Comment: which answer? post the crash log you are getting

Answer (score 0):

in your code,you are deleting from the final ArrayList str(why declare it final if you plan to remove/change data?) which is present in your activity.

you need to use

```
arrayAdapter.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(i))
```

then

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html for methods.

If you are using an inbuilt implementation of any class ALWAYS use the methods that it provides..or else use your custom implementation